# Sharing Data Between Subclassed Instances In Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

In Django, I have three classes like the ones below, simplified for this example.

```
Class Message(models.Model):
  sent_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now) 
  text = models.CharField(max_length=150)

Class SentMessage(Message):
  pass

Class ReceivedMessage(Message):
  pass
```

I want `SentMessage` and `ReceivedMessage` to share data, such that a `SentMessage` instance can change the values of a `ReceivedMessage` instance. Let's say that the SentMessage saves itself, updating the `text`, I would want the text to also be updated for the `ReceivedMessage`. How could I do this? Is this possible if `ReceivedMessage` and `SentMessage` both inherit from the same class?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a one-to-one relationship between `ReceivedMessage` and `SentMessage`. You could update the text on the related model in that way, I suppose.